# Component stops updating after using combineReducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

### **What is the current behavior?**

I have a Header component which should update after login data gets fetched. It checks a user's name and displays a welcome message.

When creating a store without using `combineReducers`, using only the `loginReducer` I've created everything works fine, state gets updated and then the component gets updated too. However, when using combineReducers, even though I use the same single reducer inside it, the component stops updating. I'm also using a logger middleware to display state changes and the state seems to be getting updated properly.

---

### **Code example:**

#### This works:

Please notice that I'm only showing relevant file parts here.

**`index.js`**

```
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

// Here I'm creating the store with a single reducer function
const store = createStore(loginReducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware));

const router = createRouter();

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
        { router }
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**`loginReducer.js`**

```
// Please notice that here I'm not mutating state in any way
// I'm always returning a new state as recommended by the docs
const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [REQUEST_LOGIN]: (state, action) => {
    return ({ ...state, username: action.payload.username, authHeader: 'Basic ' + base64Encode(action.payload.username + ':' + md5(action.payload.password))});
  },
  [RECEIVE_LOGIN]: (state, action) => {
    return ({ ...state, resources: action.payload.resources, isCashier: action.payload.isCashier });
  },
  [LOGOUT]: (state) => {
    return ({ ...state, username: null, resources: {}, authHeader: null, isCashier: null });
  }
}

const initialState = { isCashier: null, resources: {}, username: null };
export default function loginReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type]

  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
}

export default loginReducer;
```

**`LoginContainer.js`**

```
const mapActionCreators = {
  doLogin,
  doLogout
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  resources: state.resources,
  username: state.username
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionCreators)(Login)
```

---

#### This doesn't work:

This is the version which doesn't work, the only changes I've made were:
* I'm now wrapping the `loginReducer` inside `combineReducers`
* I changed the mapStateToProps function in order to get those properties from the nested `login` object inside the state

**`index.js`**

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login: loginReducer
});

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

// Now I'm not using the raw `loginReducer` anymore
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware));

const router = createRouter();

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
        { router }
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**`loginReducer.js`** -> This stays the same as above

**`LoginContainer.js`**

```
const mapActionCreators = {
  doLogin,
  doLogout
}

// Here I'm getting properties from `state.login` instead of `state` now due to the use of combineReducers
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  resources: state.login.resources,
  username: state.login.username
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionCreators)(Login)
```

Here's an image in which I describe the states after dispatching each one of the actions:

[image: correct]

Whenever an action is dispatched and the previous and next state are logged, they are correct, but my component won't get updated.

Am I missing something here or is this really a bug?

Comment: I am getting same issue. still not able to find answer for combinereducers implementation.

Answer (score -1):

***Please test your reducers***. ***keep state flat please***. ***use a high order component for authentication logic***. use reselect to improve performance. it a bug test your reduces. this should work. and deep nested state is not good cause it makes you state hard to think about and manage.
my code below:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
//import the reducers ou want

const authReducer = combineReducers({
  loginData: LoginReducer,
  permission: permissionReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

check this http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html